# Allow non-docker group to launch containers

Tags: linux, security, docker

As far as I understand, membership in docker group is basically equal to root privileges. I need to allow one user to execute specific container but I don't want him to be root-equivalent.

Since it's quite problematic to make bash script setgid, I was thinking about writing short executable, which would be setgid for docker group and only thing it would do is launch that specific docker container. This particular executable would be +x and owned by another user. The side-effect that ANY user could launch it is acceptable for me.

Would this bring any security over being in docker group? Or is it still trivial to break?

I doubt I'm first person to want this, how is this normally solved?

Comment: If you just need to provide a way to launch containers, have you considered Docker Remote API?

Comment: hm, didn't hear of that. but from looking at it it doesn't seem to solve my issue. `/var/run/docker.sock` is `srw-rw----` owned by `root:docker`. So again, it requires being root or in docker group to use it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to publish a TCP port for remote API so your users can use a cURL script to launch containers. See also [Protect the Docker daemon socket](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/)

Comment: I don't see a way how to allow user to run just specific container :/ So yeah, that would remove docker group requirement but wouldn't help with security at all?